# Backup/restore currently open Windows Explorer windows - with national character encoding and supporting tabs

Tags: windows-explorer, encoding

The extended script provided in this thread [Backup/restore currently open Windows Explorer windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1330196/backup-restore-currently-open-windows-explorer-windows) does not seem to support filenames with national characters like "æøåäöü" ect. The filenames are stored without accents and variations as "aoaaou".

The central part of the script seems to be:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-6 delims=/: " %%G IN ("%DATE% %TIME%") DO (    
    SET "currentDate=%%I%%H%%G%%J%%K" 
) 
set "filename=windows_explorer_restore_session_%currentDate%%docTitle%.bat"    

powershell  @^(^(New-Object -com shell.application^).Windows^(^)^).Document.Folder.Self.Path >> prevfolderpaths.txt

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN (prevfolderpaths.txt) DO (    
    set "var=%%f" 
    set "firstletters=!var:~0,2!"    
    IF "!firstletters!" == "::" ( ECHO start /min shell:%%~f >> %filename%) ELSE ( ECHO start /min "" "%%~f" >> %filename%)    
)
```

I suspect that the problem occurs when converting the result from the Powershell request into  batch file variables

Also, since the answer was written, Explorer now supports Tabs. Thus rather than opening each folder as separate windows, it would be nice to restore exactly the same windows as they were when running the script, some of which will contain more than one Tab.

How do I modify the script to support this?